# Stainless steel pan discoloration

Tags: cleaning, cookware, stainless-steel

I couldn't find something that resembles this but one day I used my stainless steel pan and I think I didn't clean it properly so I woke up to discover these "stains" on it (BKF didn't help scrub them off):
[image: Discoloration 1]
[image: Discoloration 2]

**Anyone know what these could be and how to treat it? Not sure if it's even safe to cook in it anymore.**

Comment: I don't think this applies to the "brown stains question", Divi. These look more like inside stains, possibly a light residue from the food. I get them occasionally (but I ignore them).

Comment: Yeah it's not something you can "feel" on the pan, it's more like embedded inside it? I tried scrubbing but nothing sadly

Comment: We have dozens of older questions about discolorations on stainless steel, and while people sometimes describe them differently, it seems that frequently it is just a matter of word choice. Also, no matter what the supposed color, as long it is not polymerized oil, all the answers go into the same direction. So I closed as one of the older ones saying "cloudy", which roughly applies to this picture too.